# Plot arrays on white images without changing the size of the images

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, plot, image-size

Let's say I have lists like this

```
x[1] = [12, 11], y[1] = [130, 195]
```

Now I want to plot these coordinates on a white image (207*315) given by

```
white_img = np.zeros([207,315,3],dtype=np.uint8)
white_img.fill(255)
```

I plotted 20 size dots on x[1],x[2] by using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x[1], y[1], c='black', s=20)
```

I made sure the plotted images by using plt.imshow.
And I saved the images using

```
plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

Then I found out the images have axis and blanks around the images that I don't want them to have and the size of the images was 354*535.
How can I plot the coordinates without changing the size?

Comment: You'll want to use PIL instead of matplotlib for this most likely...

Comment: PIL worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Right tool for the right job.